# How can I make my Login Form Object-Oriented

Tags: c#, oop

*My problem is I don't know how to call the textboxes and buttons to my class from my form login. So I decided to put my codes inside my btnLogin events. How can I make my codes oop style?*

```
 private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 0;
            Connection connection = new Connection();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Account WHERE Username='" + txtUserName.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully!");
                this.Hide();
                main.showMeForm4(this);
            }
            else
            {
                txtPassword.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Is Incorrect");
                txtUserName.Text = "";
                txtPassword.Text = "";

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Just by using C# you're OOP but I'm thinking you're asking for something else.

Comment: Change your Class from "Private" to "Public" and you should be able to access it from other parts of the code. That is of course I'm understanding what you're asking for.

Comment: I already done it. but when I put the txtUserName & txtPassword to my class. The error is "The name txtUserName does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Can you please post more code from your different classes and use comments to show exactly what you're trying to accomplish. You can't simply call txtUserName you'd need to call txtUserName.SomeMethod(); (Usually Main;)

Comment: How can I do it. Can you please help me. What is best way to make my login form object-oriented? I have a class but it is for insert and update records

Comment: Is this from a popup form? And you try to access some controls on your mainform?

Comment: @PoulBak I've asked him 3x now for more information and he's yet to update post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your business logic to a separate class:
Do not concat SQL query ([SQL Injections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-windows-form?view=vs-2017)).
BusinessLogic class

```
public bool Authorize(string userName, string userPassword)
       {
            Connection connection = new Connection();
            string sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM tbl_Account WHERE Username=@userName and Password=@userPassword";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName",userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userPassword",userPassword);
            int count = 0;
            try
            {
               conn.Open();
               int count = int.TryParse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());                
            }
            finally
            {
              con.Close();
            }
            return count==1;
       }
```

Call it:

```
BusinessLogic businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (businessLogic.Authorize(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully!");
                 this.Hide();
                 main.showMeForm4(this);
            }
            else
            {
                 txtPassword.Focus();
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Is Incorrect");
                txtUserName.Text = "";
                txtPassword.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: how about the this code? `this.Hide(); main.showMeForm4(this);` where do I put it?

Comment: It always show "Username or Password Is Incorrect" even I put it right

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. It's ok now sir!

Comment: You can also use ExecuteScalar with Select Count(*) as I added to the sample.